# where do I define entity "context" ( unknown entity "Context" ) -using AIDE

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to java so you have use pictures and small words :)
Anyway I've decided to learn write for Android straight off the bat.
I'm using AIDE so my errors are from there not eclipse.

First of all I'm struggling to understand why examples are written as below:

```
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!"; 
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration); 
toast.show();
```

It really make it hard to work out if the last line of code is referencing toast, toast or toast?

Secondly I've pasted the example code into my project and getting the error:

```
unknown entity "Context"
```

I think I need to import something?
I've searched but can't find it.

Comment: why don't you use eclipse ? download ADT, it has already android implemented in it, it handles automaticly the imports, as well as many other things, besides, eclipse is the most powerful IDE for android

Comment: Toast : Uppercase T, is the class Toast; toast : all lowercase, is an instance of the class

Comment: I'd recommend Android Studio over Eclipse if you're starting now. However, both would make it obvious (or automatic) that you need to add `import android.content.Context;` to the top of your file.


EDIT: and in your code context is in lower case. Activity extends Context so if you are in your Activity then you can just use `this` instead of `context`

Answer (score 1):

The toast is an instance of an object that shows a very temporary popup message on the screen.

The "context" is something you need to fill, which may be the current activity or anything that extends from the class Context. see [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) for the full description of the makeToast function.

usually it's inside an activity, so you might use:

```
class MainActivity {

...onCreate(...) {
...
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, duration); 
toast.show();
```